# Why does it appear as though the await commands are having no effect?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, async-await

I have an issue where it seems as though the `await` statements aren't actually behaving as intended.

If I understand correctly, `await this.$socket.emit('get_current_user' ...` should actually finish before the next statement which is `console.log(this.current_user)`

But it appears that that isn't the case.

```
        // get user object from server
        await this.$socket.emit('get_current_user', async (current_user) => {
            if (current_user) {
                this.current_user = await current_user // threw this in just to try it...
                console.log(this.current_user) // this shows the expected output
                // {__ob__: Observer}
                // created_at: (...)
                // nickname: (...)
                // primary_room_id: (...)
                // registered: (...)
            } else {
                // stuff
            }
        })

        console.log(this.current_user) // does not show expected output
        // appears to output an empty object
        // {__ob__: Observer}
        // __ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
        // __proto__: Object
        //
        // none of the expected properties are present (such as nickname)
```

Comment: Just to make sure: `this.$socket.emit` returns a Promise, right?

Comment: Also, the `async` modifier should be on the function that includes this fragment.

Comment: @Mathyn it appears that it does not return a promise.

Comment: If no promise is returned you cannot use await. I'm guessing Javascript will then simply skip it?

Comment: I suppose so...

Answer (score 1):

You can't immediately log something out after await/async, it won't be ready. Because the async call may have not completed yet. Javascript code executes from the top down. Since you're already using `async/await`, you can just refactor it in this way:

```
const current_user = await this.$socket.emit('get_current_user')

this.current_user = current_user

console.log(this.current_user)
```

Comment: `this.$socket.emit` won't have an actual return value though. the only way to get a return value is by passing a callback to `.emit`

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
let user = await new Promise((accept, reject) => {
   this.$socket.emit('get_current_user', current_user => {
        if (current_user) {
            accept(current_user)
        } else {
            reject(null)
        }
    })
})
```

To wait after some code that need a callback, you have to create a promise. await will wait after the passed promise resolves.

It's not in the question but I feel a good exercice to make a generic with that:

```
const fromSocket = address => new Promise((accept, reject) => 
   this.$socket.emit(
      address, 
      obj => obj && accept(obj) || reject(null)
   )
)

let user = await fromSocket('get_current_user')
```